# Open fails, fopen doesn't

Tags: c, posix

Whenever I use `open` I get the permission denied error. But when I use `fopen` it opens the file fine. What is wrong with my code?

```
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
char *filename = "dataread.txt";

rec = open(filename ,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,mode);
if(rec == -1)
{
    perror("\nopen error 1:");
    exit(1);
}
```

Error:

> open error 1:: Permission denied

With `fopen` I don't get this error.

Comment: `filename` should be a `const char *`, by the way.

Comment: How are you calling `fopen`? And I removed the C++ tag as I haven't seen any C++.

Comment: @Kerrek: Why? Just because `open` takes a `const char *` (meaning it won't modify the string you pass) doesn't mean you have to use a `const char *` variable (or any pointer variable whatsoever) to store the address of the string you want to pass.

Comment: R.: Because a string literal is a pointer to non-mutable data. It's not related to the question, just a general point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an `int rec=0;` var declaration and the necessary includes files and then compiled your code.
It runs with no errors as a normal user in my Fedora 15 laptop. Check the dir/file permissions you are running this on, the problems does not seem to be in the code.